# How to use cycle in django with two columns?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I created one section divided into two columns. Each of the columns is to represent one blog entry. Unfortunately, two columns are currently assigned one and the same entry, and they will be two separate. I don't quite understand how to use the cycle tag correctly in this case.

[example http://imgbox.com/NWO7qA7S](http://imgbox.com/NWO7qA7S)

I use the bootstrap 4 and django 2.2 frameworks to create the page. I tried various combinations, but understanding the operation of the cycle tag is unclear to me.

```
{% for post in posts %}

<section class="bg-light py-5" id="aktualnosci">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Informacje o zmianach w prawie podatkowym</h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p class="text-paragraph pt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam iure consectetur accusantium delectus, iusto culpa mollitia eum molestiae at? Ab!</p>
        <div class="row py-3">

    <!-- FIRST POST -->

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="news-card">
                    <div class="text-center text-white bg-blue d-flex align-items-center news-card-date">
                        <div class="mx-auto news-card-date-body w-75">
                            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt d-none d-block mx-auto"></i>
                            <span class="d-block news-card-date-value mt-1">{{ post.published }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-card-body">
                        <div class="news-card-img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'main/images/126.jpg' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-card-content">
                            <div class="news-card-content-inner">
                                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                <p class="text-paragraph">{{ post.lead }}</p>
                                <a class="pb-2" href="#">Czytaj więcej</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!-- SECOND POST -->

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="news-card">
                    <div class="text-center text-white bg-blue d-flex align-items-center news-card-date">
                        <div class="mx-auto news-card-date-body w-75">
                            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt d-none d-block mx-auto"></i>
                            <span class="d-block news-card-date-value mt-1">{{ post.published }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-card-body">
                        <div class="news-card-img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'main/images/287.jpg' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-card-content">
                            <div class="news-card-content-inner">
                                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                <p class="text-paragraph">{{ post.lead }}</p>
                                <a class="pb-2" href="#">Czytaj więcej</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="pt-2" href="{% url 'posts:posts_list'  %}">Zobacz wszystkie &gt; &gt; </a>
    </div>
</section>

{% endfor  %}
```

I am currently receiving duplicate one post in both columns. Ultimately, I would like to receive two different posts in two columns in one section. Next, I'd like to add a second section when creating the third entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your loop is just in the wrong place. I don't think you need to use the `cycle` tag for this.

Try this:

```
<section class="bg-light py-5" id="aktualnosci">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Informacje o zmianach w prawie podatkowym</h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p class="text-paragraph pt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam iure consectetur accusantium delectus, iusto culpa mollitia eum molestiae at? Ab!</p>
        <div class="row py-3">
            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="news-card">
                    <div class="text-center text-white bg-blue d-flex align-items-center news-card-date">
                        <div class="mx-auto news-card-date-body w-75">
                            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt d-none d-block mx-auto"></i>
                            <span class="d-block news-card-date-value mt-1">{{ post.published }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-card-body">
                        <div class="news-card-img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'main/images/126.jpg' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="news-card-content">
                            <div class="news-card-content-inner">
                                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                <p class="text-paragraph">{{ post.lead }}</p>
                                <a class="pb-2" href="#">Czytaj więcej</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <a class="pt-2" href="{% url 'posts:posts_list'  %}">Zobacz wszystkie &gt; &gt; </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Essentially, you want to add a new column for each `post` in `posts`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for your help. This solves the first level of the problem, but there is a second one. I would like to see the third post on the website, in the second section below. How to do it ?

Comment: The answer I posted will render as many posts as you want, it will post two per row and then skip to the new "row". Even if you have 15 points, it will show all of them, two at a time. This is because we are using `col-lg-6` which is half of the 12 columns per row that the Bootstrap grid uses.

Comment: I'm sorry. Indeed you are right. I made a mistake in my code. Thanks again for your help :)